# Structural engineering: Would I need a beam for this?

Tags: structural-engineering, beam

If I was designing a simple gabled house with a 21 ft vaulted ceiling as the peak of the roof, and the house was about 32 ft x 40 ft with no load bearing walls (other than the 4 exterior walls)...  would I need a beam across the entire peak of the house? If so would it have to be steel cause of the 40 ft span?

Comment: Depends what the building codes / regs say in your country or State / county ...

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a ['Naive design' question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/188/1832). Such questions are excessively broad and are therefore not a good fit for our format. See if you can [edit] your question to make it specific and answerable.

Comment: Please keep in mind that practising professional engineering with out a license will get you in lots of trouble ( at least in America and Canada). Consulting a licensed engineer would be the best option here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not need a steel beam . Although steel would give you the lowest profile. An engineered wood beam would be more typical ; truss type or laminated beam . I guess a wood beam would be about 2 feet high/deep. They will both meet code anywhere but you you will need to know the weight of your roof and determine how you will provide lateral stability. So professional design will be needed.

Comment: Will that meet building code in the OP's country?

Comment: For fun I looked up one span in some table.  A southern pine 2 X 12 is good for 20' 9" for a typical load. So , you will need a truss or laminated beam.